# beamer only compiles once

Tags: beamer, compiling, winedt

I am making changes to a `beamer` file, it will compile once, but then not a second time.  It gives all sorts of different errors each time.

> Ex.  It says :  I can't write on file '___.pdf'
>
> Ex.  Sometimes, the pdf will pop up immediately, before it complies
>   and say -There was an error opening the document.  Access denied.

I'll resave the exact same code under a file name and it will compile, but again only once.

Update:  I am using Winedt and I read the error again and it says "can't remove ____.synctex (file is open or read only)".  I tried to delete the file myself and it says I must be an administrator to do so, which is odd because I am the administrator (or so I thought??).

Help!

Comment: Well, either there is a lock on some files or a severe error in your documents, that only occur in the second run (e.g. when the `.aux` file is read). Try to remove all auxiliary files

Comment: In case this does not help, can you compose a MWE that illustrates your problem?

Comment: What is your pdf viewer?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: This seems not to be a new problem to you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308991/winedt-wont-compile-unless-i-rename-and-save

Comment: No, it is not a new problem, but normally I can recompile a few times before it does it. My dissertation is up to version 57, but I'm creating a beamer for my defense and just today alone, I have added about 20 new versions.

Comment: @Laura Winedt is your (La)TeX *editor*. What is your PDF *viewer* ? Adobe Reader ? Sumatra ? Foxit Reader ? PDF-XChange ? Other ?

Comment: my bad.  adobe reader.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments